# Jupyter Notebook Not Recognizing "import torch"

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, conda

To install `PyTorch` on Ubuntu, as instructed by the official website, I did `pip3 install torch torchvision`, and I am able to run `PyTorch` using the `python3.5` command.

However, when I run `Jupyter Notebook` (I'm just running `Jupyter Notebook` in the terminal and using Chrome to access my notebooks), it doesn't recognize the package, throwing `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'` at me.

The other odd thing is that **`PyTorch` seems to have only been installed on `Python 3.5`** and not on `Python 3.6` because:

```
➜  ~ python3.5 -c "import torch; print(torch.__version__)"     
0.4.1
➜  ~ python3.6 -c "import torch; print(torch.__version__)"     
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'
➜  ~
```

Therefore I'm guessing that `Jupyter Notebook` is not using `Python 3.5`.

This is the result when I type `python` in my terminal and press `TAB`:

```
➜  ~ python
python             python2.7          python3.5          python3.5m         python3.6          python3.6m         python3-config     python3m-config  
python2            python3            python3.5-config   python3.5m-config  python3.6-config   python3.6m-config  python3m
```

Also, when I run `which python`, I get `/home/mhy/anaconda3/bin/python` since I installed `Anaconda` recently. I then activated my `env` and installed `PyTorch` using the following commands:

```
source activate my_env
conda install torch torchvision
```

But I wasnt able to run `PyTorch` on `Anaconda` either.

Comment: be use to use the jupyter for python 3.5

Comment: How can I tell my Jupyter to run notebooks using Python3.5?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, check whether you run your Jupyter notebook on the different environment than the one where PyTorch is installed:

```
(my_env) instance-1:~$ source activate my_env
(my_env) instance-1:~$ python
>>> import  sys
>>> print(sys.executable)
/home/instance-1/anaconda3/envs/my_env/bin/python
```

and then run the notebook in the `my_env` environment:
`(my_env) instance-1:~$ jupyter notebook`
And in the notebook execute `print(sys.executable)`, then if you get something like `‘/home/instance-1/anaconda3/bin/python’`, you have created the notebook in the environment Jupyter uses as a default.

I have been struggling with the same problem, once I discovered that in the Jupyter notebook console you have options to create notebooks in different environments. So just go to the 'New' section and select something like `Python(myenv)` to create a notebook in the desired environment(`my_env` in this case).

Another possible solution might be to install Jupyter into your environment: activate the desired environment and run `conda install -c anaconda jupyter`

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Алиса Газизуллина, it worked for me! I did notice however that my environment had to have to highest python version (3.8.3.) to get it working! If I used the exact same environment only but a lower pyhton version (3.8.1. or 2.7. or something), it wouldn't work.